# How to reset author of earlier commit?

Tags: git

My local commits have wrong email so I used the following command to reset it. However, it only reset the latest local commit. How to reset the earlier ones?

```
git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit
```

Comment: Maybe just try to checkout earlier (or any other that you want to amend) commit and then execute this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do (you may need to increase/decrease 20 according to how far back the commit you want to edit is):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~20
```

and, for the commit you want to amend, replace `pick` with `edit` (in the interactive window). Save, and close.

Then, do `git commit --amend`, make your change, and let the rebase continue.

Comment: I have two commits and so I just need to amend the first one now.

Comment: I did `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and now it stays in my previous commit. How to rebase back to my latest commit?

Comment: did you finish the rebase?

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you have a linear history, you can reset the authorship of all commits with

```
git rebase -i --exec 'git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit' --root
```

If only a subset of commits is affected, which still must be all in a linear history, replace `--root` with the commit ID before the first one of yours.