# Git rebase - move head back to my latest commit?

Tags: git

I have a few commits and I need to fix my previous commit so I did.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
# change the commit's pick to edit
# ....
```

How to change the HEAD back to my latest commit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset author of earlier commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64358024/how-to-reset-author-of-earlier-commit) You were told the answer there but you didn’t do it.

Comment: One question is about update commit and one is about head.

Comment: No, the answer about updating the commit told you to continue the rebase but you didn’t.

Comment: Yes, the answer mentioned "let the rebase continue.". But it's unclear for someone new to Git rebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing a commit in rebase you need to continue the rebase

```
git rebase --continue
```

This will finish the rebase and get you back to commit you were on (well, the rebased version of it)