# How do I fix the email in the 10 latest git commits?

Tags: git

I want to fix the email in the 10 most recent git commits (while keeping the timestamp when they were originally committed, like [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) does).

Alas, I cannot use [`--reset-author`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64358024/850781) because it also [resets the timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71225139/850781).

I suppose I can use [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch), then use [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to fix the email, and then [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) to apply them.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Which timestamp are you concerned about?

Comment: I want to keep the date when each patch was originally committed.

Comment: Commit timestamps are uniquely generated for each commit. I don't think you can manipulate them?

Comment: I am pretty sure `git rebase` allows me to modify commits while keeping timestamps.

Comment: You can set explicit committer and author dates using the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` and `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` environment variables. Doing this with multiple commits will probably require a little scripting but should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out I just had to do something similar. It looked a bit like this:

```
git rebase HEAD~4 -x 'GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$(git  show --format=%ad -s)" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git show --format=%cd -s)" git commit --amend -CHEAD --author "Bob <bob@example.com>"'
```

This resets the author to "Bob bob@example.com" on the most recent 4 commits, preserving both the committer and author dates.

Comment: thank you! note that `git ci` does not exist by default.

Comment: Indeed, that's an alias I forgot to fix. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

Git filter-repo is probably the best tool for this! Construct a mailmap like so:

```
Old Name <old-email@stuff.com> Correct Name <your-email@stuff.com>
```

Save this in a file called mailmap.txt or something (it can be named anything).

Then, run git filter-repo in a fresh clone:

```
git filter-repo --mailmap path/to/mailmap.txt
```

Comment: `filter-repo` does not appear to be a standard git command

Comment: ...and I posted a solution earlier that uses `git rebase`, which *is* a standard git command.