# Git reset commit timestamp - how do I recover?

Tags: git

I did [`git commit --amend --reset-author`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64358024/850781) and it reset the timestamp to today.

Is there a way to recover the original timestamp? I.e.,

1. Find out what it was ([`git reflog --pretty`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) shows it, as suggested by @evolutionxbox
   in a comment)
2. Edit the commit and modify the timestamp

Comment: `git reflog` might be able to tell you what the old commit was.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: thanks, that solves the 1st problem; now, what about the 2nd one?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--Cltcommitgt seems to show that you can reuse the timestamp?

Comment: Answer to the second question is [probably here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/454734/184546).

Comment: Note that when you do this, you're actually creating *new and different* commits (with new, unique hash IDs). If you're the only one with the old commits, you don't have to care about this, but if you've sent the old (wrong-author/wrong-date) commits to some other Git, you do, because Git identifies commits by hash ID. The branch name, if any, is mainly for humans.